# Azure virtual network : unable to delete

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

I have created a couple of Virtual Networks on my Azure account. All of them have point-to-site connectivity enabled. But I dont have any connections actively connected to the network. When I go to the "configure" page for eahc of these networks in the management portal, I see a message sayingthe network is in use and I am unable to delete these networks.

Why does this happen? How can I delete these networks?

Comment: You can try [my](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42545174/465053) solution. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you also have created Gateways for these networks. You have to delete the gateway for the network first, before you are able to delete the network.

[This particular part of online documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn221918.aspx) describes how to delete a Virtual Network Gateway.

Comment: I dont get "Delete gateway" option on the bottom menu because the network is in use

Comment: Gateway can be deleted from the "Dashboard" (main screen of the network), not "Configure" or other screens. And there must be no computers connected to it on the Point-to-site VPN.

Answer (score 0):

The gateway and the virtual machines attached to the availability set. When you delete the virtual machine but don't delete the disk, you can restore it again.